# Why is this proof of the Archimedean property not using circular logic?

Tags: real-analysis

**Archimedean Property (copied from Ivan Wilde’s excellent lecture notes)**

For any given $x \in\mathbb R$, there is some $n \in\mathbb N$ such that $n > x$.

Proof. Let $x \in\mathbb R$ be given. We use the method of “proof by contradiction” — so suppose that there is no $n\in\mathbb N$ obeying $n > x$. This means that $n ≤ x$ for all $n ∈ \Bbb N$, that is, $x$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb N$ in $\Bbb R$. By the completeness property, (A14), $\mathbb N$ has a least upper bound, $α$, say. Then $α$ is an upper bound for $\Bbb N$ so that

$$n ≤ α\tag{$*$}$$

for all $n ∈\Bbb N$. Since $α$ is the least upper bound, $α − 1$ cannot be an upper bound for $\Bbb N$ and so there must be some $k ∈\Bbb N$ such that $α − 1 < k$. But we can rewrite this as $α < k + 1$ which contradicts (∗) since $k + 1 ∈\Bbb N$. We conclude that there is some $n ∈ \Bbb N$ obeying $n > x$, as claimed.  [Proof ends]

**My problem is with $k + 1 ∈ \Bbb N$ (last para): under the ‘contradictory hypothesis’ surely $k+1 > \alpha$ and therefore specifically NOT in $\Bbb N$.  What am I missing here?**

Comment: I think the thing you're missing is that the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ says that $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies n+1\in\mathbb{N}$. Since we're given that $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then of necessity we have $k+1\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You are not missing anything. The contradiction that bothers you is exactly what forces you to reject the premise that there is some number greater than all the integers.

Comment: @EarthDemon You correctly argued that assuming the Archimedean property false mplies that there is an integer such that adding $1$ to it gets you a noninteger. That is precisely the contradiction you hoped to find. So the Archimedean property must hold.

Comment: @EarthDemon Why would that implication be suspended? The statement is definitionally true of $\mathbb{N}$ and it's what allows this proof to work in the first place. If you remove the axiom that $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies n+1\in\mathbb{N}$ then the Archimedean property doesn't necessarily hold. (e.g. $\{0\}$ satisfies all the other axioms of $\mathbb{N}$ and clearly does not admit the Archimedean property.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki My point is specifically that ∈ℕ⟹+1∈ℕ is used in the contradictory phase of the proof whereby that implication is suspended.  Assuming the contradictory hypothesis is true I claim $k+1 \notin \mathbb N$ it is in $\mathbb R$.  Is the following consistent with the sense of the text “a contradiction since $k+1$ cannot be in $\mathbb N$”

Comment: @EthanBolker gah I managed to delete my earlier reply to you sorry

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I just watched a video on the proof and he also relies on the $n+1 \in \mathbb N$ idea - but surely this is circular logic - you are invoking the very thing we are trying to prove, and worse, doing it in the contradictory phase of the argument.  I understand UPF inside out, induction and various other proofs but this is troubling me….

Comment: We're not trying to prove that $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies n+1\in\mathbb{N}$; the _only_ 'very thing' we're trying to prove is that for each real number $r$ there's an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\gt r$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki ok understood now thank you.  The phrase ‘definitionally true’ got me over the line.